# creating listview and intent to barcode scanner and return result without displaying and send result data to webserver

Tags: android, listview, resources, android-intent, webserver

I am trying to create a listview through resource and each would open the barcode scanner(using android integrate) and return the result without displaying and send the data result to the webserver(By the way, I have succeeded to send a data to webserver as text file and would like to know how to grab that data from the barcode without displaying and send the data result to the webserver as text file). I am having problems trying to succeed in this step. (android 1.5 device, project is 2.2 with sdk 3 using eclipse)

```
string.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, MainActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">company</string>
<string-array name="customer_service_group">
<item>Start Trip</item>
<item>Clock In</item>
<item>Customer Svc</item>
<item>Independent Inspection</item>
<item>Pick Up</item>
<item>Log Out</item>
</string-array>
</resources>

MainActivity.java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[]Customer;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] Customer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.customer_service_group);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, Customer));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Intent i = new Intent("com.merrill.IntentIntegrator");
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
          }

        });}

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == request_Code) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
                ------not sure what to put here-----
    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the errors are setListAdapter, list_item, and getListView. Im not sure why there's an error even if imported

Comment: can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code that should get started receiving the result from BarcodeScanner intent:

```
/*Here is where we come back after the Barcode Scanner is done*/
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // contents contains whatever the code was
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

            // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            // Handle successful scan. In this example I just put the results into the TextView
            resultsTxt.setText(format + "\n" + contents);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel. If the user presses 'back' before a code is scanned.
            resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: instead of this line

```
resultsTxt.setText(format + "\n" + contents);
```

change it to send contents to your server. If you have a method set up for interacting with your server then it would be something like

```
sendDataToServer(contents);
```

Comment: thanks! I actually forgot to update my code with this sample and still looking for a way to not display the result data and automatically send the data to webserver.

Comment: the data that was scanned can be found inside the variable content. You just need to send that String to your server. See my edit for one possible way you could have it set up.

Comment: thanks again Tim. Can you check my code what could I be missing? I wasn't able to compile it as there's more than a few error. Im still trying to figure out how to get it to run.